# froala editor not working perfectly

Tags: php, html, editor, froala

I am using froala editor for insert CMS content to database.But it not work perfectly , I am arrange content in left side and image in right side , it aligned correctly in editor , but in my view page (get content from database) it not aligned correctly.

```
In editor
```

[image: In editor]

```
In View page
```

[image]

Anyone please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include `froala_page.min.css` in your view to fix image alignment.

Also, in edit mode, the editor text is aligned to left. In your view mode the text is aligned to center because you have some CSS that overrides that.

Comment: I am not able to find this file. Can you please help?

Comment: Did you able to relove thsi ?