# Froala showing content differently in view-only page

Tags: froala

I am using Froala to create html content with images. The problem is that the images are not aligned properly in view-only mode and always appear left-aligned. The accepted answer on this page https://stackoverflow.com/a/26452421/2211098 suggests use of froala_page.min.css, but I cannot find that file in the sources. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`froala_page.min.css` was changed recently to `froala_content.min.css` and `froala_style.min.css`. Read the `Display Edited Content` section from https://editor.froala.com/docs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Those files are already included in my app the way they are described in docs. But in editor the image appears in the center of the div and in view-only mode it is left aligned.

Comment: Probably you're not saving the content right. If the image doesn't has the class `fr-tag` then the content is not saved right.

If you use JS to save the content, you should use `getHTML` as on https://editor.froala.com/examples/getHTML.